# SQL: delete parent when child does not exist

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, parent-child

I have two tables:

tblEmployee

```
EmployeeID (PK), Name, Age, Department
```

tblDesignation

```
EmployeeID(FK), Designation, DesignationID
```

I need help to write a stored procedure to delete an employee record only if it does not have a record in the designation table. (delete employeeID only if there is no designation assigned)

I am not sure if I should use the ON DELETE RESTRICT constraint or NOT EXISTS clause.

Comment: Would appreciate if you share what have you tried so far to get your output

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: I am using SQL server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can have below code for your purpose. Please excuse with syntax

```
create procedure usp_deleteemployee
as 
begin
    delete from tblEmployee 
    where id not in (select empid from tblDesignation);
end
```

Or you can try with exist also. Not sure about syntax

```
DELETE tblEmployee 
FROM tblEmployee 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM tblDesignation 
                  WHERE tblEmployee.Id = tblDesignation.empid)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like below.

```
DELETE
E
FROM
tblEmployee E
LEFT JOIN tblDesignation D
ON E.EmployeeID = D.EmployeeID
WHERE
D.EmployeeID IS NULL
```

Hope this Helps!!

Comment: Thanks but I want to delete it with ID. I do not want to delete all the records. Creating a parameter for EmployeeID and deleting only records for which I give the value of the EmployeeID.